# How is the extended real number line modeled?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

In set theory, numbers are often constructed, e.g. from nestings of sets which eventually contain the empty set. The operations are defined in term of taking unions etc.etc.

The extended real number line hat plus and minus infinity $\infty,-\infty$ in addition to the reals, and they fulfill [certain axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations).

> How are the two objects "$\infty$" and "$-\infty$" of the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ modeled in rigorous set theory?

I figure it might be related to ordinal numbers. But these are *two* things and they behave somewhat similarly. So I wonder what they are made of, set theoretically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is using the Dedekind cut construction of the real numbers from the rationals. If one relaxes the requirement that the left and right sets of a Dedekind cut must be nonempty, one has the two cuts $(\emptyset, \mathbb{Q})$ and $(\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset)$. These can be identified with $-\infty$ and $\infty$, respectively.

Then we have, for example, the following as a natural result:

- $\infty + \infty = \infty$ (add the elements of the left set of $\infty$, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}$ (that is, form the set $\{ x + y : x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, to those of itself and you get $\mathbb{Q}$ again, same goes for the right set)
- $-\infty + -\infty = -\infty$ (add the elements of the left set of $-\infty$, i.e. $\emptyset$, to those of itself and you get $\emptyset$ again, same goes for the right set)
- $a + \infty = \infty$ (for a non-infinity cut $a$, note that if you add the elements of the left set of $a$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, you just get $\mathbb{Q}$ again)

all from the usual definitions of addition of Dedekind cuts. Note that $-\infty + \infty$ doesn't work, though, since if we try that, both the left and right set collapse, which is not a valid cut. But we expect that since we usually consider $-\infty + \infty = \infty - \infty$ undefined.

Answer (score 7):

All you need is two objects that are not in $\mathbb R$, so you may let $\infty=\{\mathbb R\}$ and $-\infty=\{\{\mathbb R\}\}$, for example.

Comment: And is it then clear how plus and times work, such that e.g. $(-1)\cdot(-\infty)=\infty$? Do we have to make a case by case definition or can some union operations etc. naturally be taken over?

Comment: @NickKidman: Yes, you need a case-by-case definition. That's also more honest than the pseudo-Dedekind-cut construction which somewhat abuses internal implementation details of the real numbers in order to give you something (the extended real line) that it ought to be possible to understand _without_ worrying about how the reals themselves are constructed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: But is a case by case definition conform with model theory? Sounds more like active computation that truth by static semantics.

Comment: @Nick: What would be wrong with that? Model theory just wants you to have functions that implement this-or-that -- how you get them (such as by case-by-case definitions) is not its problem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I might not know enough about it, but if the two infinitis are defined as in the above answer, I thought to check if $\infty+(-\infty)=0$ is true or false, I'd have to be able to check if $\{\mathbb R\}"+"\{\{\mathbb R\}\}$ holds and so $"+"$ must be something set theoretic which makes it true or false. Just like addition of numbers is defined in terms of unions etc., not something computational like if-then operations.

Comment: @NickKidman: Yes, you need to have a definition of "$+$" that explicitly tells you what the meaning of somthing like $\infty+(-\infty)$ is. That's a feature, not a bug -- because actually, you _can't_ find any definition of addition on the extended real line that works well in _all_ such corner cases. This fact would be less visible if you just took over a formula that happens to work for Dedekind cuts.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: The only point, I guess, of the "pseudo-cut" construction (wouldn't some of the comments you make here be a good idea to put on the post I made about the pseudo-cut construction?), was to point out a way in which you could get infinity elements with a representation (set-theoretic construction) that is like the reals. Though I suppose, one can argue "$\infty$" is not a real, so should not have the same representation. Then again, the original poster mentioned "similarity to reals", suggesting the want of a similar construction.