# Existence of extended real number system

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

How can we prove the existence of Extended real no. such that order and addition and multiplication (which are also relation means set) are also extended from real no. system.

Can you please provide some reference

Comment: If you accept the existence of the real numbers, the extended real numbers just come from adjoining two more symbols, $\pm \infty$, together with the relevant operations defined when they make sense. There's only a finite number of cases to spell out there.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein But extended real no. system is a set. How can we say such a system exist. We have to take union of real no. system with two sets whose elements are + and - infinity. Which set we are choosing. Will any set will work?

Comment: If you want everything to be a set, just add two sets that for sure are different from each other than any real number.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay and add ordered pairs in relation according to need(which makes no ambiguity as finite cases we considering) Right?

Comment: A closely related (same?) question with some answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459067/how-is-the-extended-real-number-line-modeled

Comment: @Sushil: Yes, we add the right ordered pairs to take care of the arithmetic. Addition is no longer a function, unless we add still another object for DNE (does not exist).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes this I get we have 1-1 relation now. Oh this I didn't even think that we can even add DNE