# If $f(x)$ is undefined for $x=-1$, can $-1$ be included in the domain of $f$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function), in mathematics, the domain or set of departure of a function is the set into which all of the input of the function is constrained to fall. So, in $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$, $x=-1$ is a valid input I think, even though $f(x)$ becomes undefined. So, can $x=-1$ fall within the domain of $f$?

Comment: I think I'm wrong; because if I'm right, then any function could have any domain and the existence of domains would serve no purpose.

Comment: See the examples section of the page you linked. That will give you an answer.

Comment: @soupless gotcha man

Comment: When you put x=-1 then there is no real value of f(x)
and for domain, every element must be mapped to its range

Comment: It can be done in a more advanced setting in which you regard $f$ as a map $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$ where set-theoretically you can define $\infty,-\infty$ set-theoretically (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459067/how-is-the-extended-real-number-line-modeled). But if you regard $f$ as a map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then of course there is no $y \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f(y)=-1$, this becomes ill-defined.

Comment: @Mathphysmeister: You have too many infinities, I think. Is $f(-1) +\infty$ or $-\infty$? In this case, better to use the [projectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line) $\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ as the range.

Comment: @TonyK . Yes I agree. I left the definition of $f(-1)$ open. But indeed in order to be a map you need that $-1$ maps to either $-\infty$ or $\infty$. If it does both at the same time, it would not be a map. Therefore I left this implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To say that $f(-1)$ is undefined is to say that $f$ does not have an
  agreed value when $x=-1.$
- To say that $-1$ is in function $f$'s domain is to say that $f(-1)$
  has a particular value.

Clearly then, the answer to your posed question is No.

P.S. When a function $g$ is extended like in Masacroso's answer, then the resultant function $g_e$ is a different function from the original one.

Answer (score 1):

For any function $f:X\to Y$ you can easily construct any other function $\tilde f:\bar X\to Y$ for any $\bar X\supset X$ such that $\tilde f|_X=f$. In this context we say that $\tilde f$ is an extension of $f$.

By example in your case you can set

$$
\tilde f(x):=\begin{cases}
f(x),&\text{ if }x\neq -1\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

for $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1\}\to \mathbb{R},\, x\mapsto \frac{x}{x+1}$.